# How to auto remove an expired record from a database?

Tags: database, datetime

We are building a large stock and forex trading platform using a relational database. At any point during the day there will be thousands, if not millions, of records in our Orders table. Some orders, if not fulfilled immediately, expire and must be removed from this table, otherwise, the table grows very quickly. Each order has an expiration time. Once an order expires it must be deleted. Attempting to do this manually using a scheduled job that scans and deletes records is very slow and hinders the performance of the system. We need to force the record to basically delete itself.

Is there way to configure any RDBMS database to automatically remove a record based on a date/time field if the time occurs in the past?

Answer (score 1):

Since you most likely will have to implement complex order handling, e.g. limit orders, stop-limit orders etc. you need a robust mechanism for monitoring and executing orders in **real time**. This process is not only limited to expired orders. This is a core mechanism in a trading platform and you will have to design a robust solution that fulfill your needs.

To answer your question: Delete expired orders as part of your normal order handling.

Answer (score 1):

Why must the row be deleted?

I think you are putting the cart before the horse here.  If a row is expired, it can be made "invisible" to other parts of the system in many ways, including views which only show orders meeting certain criteria.  Having extra deleted rows around should not hamper performance if your database is appropriately indexed.

What level of auditing and tracking is necessary?  Is no analysis ever done on expired orders?

Do fulfilled orders become some other kind of document/entity?

There are techniques in many databases which allow you to partition tables.  Using the partition function, it is possible to regularly purge partitions (of like rows) much more easily.

Comment: It must be deleted to reduce the size of the table; creating a view does not help because the size of the table has not changes.

Comment: @user660788 It worries me that you are deleting data from a financial system.  It worries me that that appears to be a requirement.  It worries me that there will be no traceability.

Comment: ummm, stop worrying so much, it's going to be alright. We are moving the records from one table to another, not deleting.

Comment: @user660788 That's not what your question was about. If you are doing this as part of a "move" operation, how are you going to ensure that when an expired record automatically removes itself (as your question asked) that it has been copied to this other location. RDBMS are made for storing billions of rows without performance effects if you aren't reading or writing them. If the rows have the same schema, you could simply use partitioning and appropriate choice of indexes for purge maintenance and read/write performance.

Answer (score 0):

You have not specified what DB you are using but lets assume you use MSSQL you could create a agent job that runs periodicly, but you are saying that that might not be a solution for you.

So what t about having an Insert Trigger that when new record is inserted you delete all the record that are expired? This will keep number of record all relatively small.

Comment: doesn't matter, any database that supports it we will be open to using